# Unable to connect from a WSUS MMC console (upstream) to another server (Downstream)

Tags: windows, ssl, updates, http, wsus

I took this image here and this is what i wish to achieve

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhVxd.png

Hi All, I have tried performing this by right clicking on the WSUS MMC to connect to another computer but no success.

Note: his is being performed on AWS and we have an Upstream and many downstream servers.

The downstream all connect to the upstream using SSL on port 8531 and the local server within each downstream using port 8530. Everything is fine till till stage and updates are pushed successfully.

No, how do i manage other wsus servers from the upstream using a single MMC console. This is my problem. I have a Security group rules in place and Allowed these port via the windows firewall.

I keep getting different erros, such as to complete the post installation and also to check the SSL. This error is not correct and note: from the upstream to downstream it can telnet via 8530 and vice versa.

Also i read, I will have to change the port to 80 (http) and this is not our use case, changed and it still didnt work)

Can anyone advise?